# Data context on JsViews' include tag

Tags: javascript, templates, jsviews

I made a snippet to show the issue I'm facing:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo 1 JsViews</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <p>{{:property}}</p>
            {^{on ~root.testFunction}}PUSH ME!{{/on}}
            {{for nestedObjects}}
                {{include #data tmpl="#template-2"/}}
            {{/for}}
        </script>

        <div id="container"></div>

        <script id="template-2" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <p>{{:~root.property}}</p>
            {^{on ~root.testFunction}}PUSH ME!{{/on}}
        </script>

        <div id="container-2"></div>
        
        <script>
        data = {
        property : "PARENT",
        testFunction : function(){ alert(this.property); },
        nestedObjects : [
            {
                id: 0,
                property: "CHILD1",
                testFunction : function(){ alert(this.property);}
            },
            {
                id: 1, 
                property: "CHILD2",
                testFunction : function(){ alert(this.property);}
            }]
        };
        /**
        * Funciones
        */
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var tmpl = $.templates("#template");
        tmpl.link("#container", data);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, in **'#template-2'** it's taking the properties from main data object, not from each **nestedObjects**' item. I know this would be the normal behaviour.

Is there a way to make include tag to take each **nestedObjects**' item and not the whole data object as context?

I know that if I remove the **'~root'** modifiers in **'#template-2'** it will work as expected, but I need it to work with **'~root'** modififer if possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, I managed to get it working in another way using a helper object, if someone has a similar issue feel free to contact me :).

Answer (score 0):

`~root` is a built-in helper that points to the top-level data that you passed to the `link()` or `render()` method. See 
http://www.jsviews.com/#contextualparams@root.

So you can't change it to have it point somewhere else. But you can create your own helpers (not using the reserved `root` name), such as:

```
{{include #data ~myroot=#data tmpl="#template-2"/}}
```

and in template-2 write

```
{{:~myroot.property}}
```

Comment: Hi Boris, I ended up by using this approach, thank you for your answer :). I take this opportunity to congratulate you for this awesome framework! :P